# How can I fix slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. Why my slider doesn't work in all classes except class `figurative`? And in class `figurative` it doesn`t disappear, when slide pages end.
2. Why my close buttons don't work in all classes except class `figurative`.

https://codepen.io/tatarusetskaya/pen/XWpzNZa

Comment: please don't paste your whole code! Just a minimal , reproducible example. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry! I tried, but it didn`t pass the test, they wrote that there is too much code and little information about the problem. So, I had to post a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always program with reusabillity in mind. If you just type a lot of rows that seemingly does the same thing, apart from a single line or word, make a single method that is more dynamic.

For example: These are doing basically the same thing:

```
function openSection() {
    document.getElementById("figurative1").style.width = "100%";
}

function openSection1() {
    document.getElementById("painting1").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeSection() {
    document.getElementById("figurative1").style.width = "0%";
}

function closeSection1() {
    document.getElementById("painting1").style.width = "0%";
}
```

How about refactor the code by using an argument?

```
function closeSection(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.width = "100%";
}

function openSection(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.width = "100%";
}
```

So instead of writing

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="openSection()">FIGURATIVE</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="openSection1()">PAINTING</a></li>
```

You can add a parameter to the function:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="openSection('figurative1')">FIGURATIVE</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="openSection('painting1')">PAINTING</a></li>
```

And do the same thing with all the close buttons as well:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeSection()">&times;</a>
```

This should be:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeSection('figurative1')">&times;</a>
```

Final code: https://codepen.io/rickard-elim/pen/yLMOeZP

EDIT: your slide method had faulty logic as well. Fixed that in my codepen.

Answer (score 0):

The close button doesn't work for the other classes because the wrong function is being called!

For example, in

```html
<div class="painting" id="painting1">
<div class="painting-content">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeSection()">&times;</a>
```

the call should be `closeSection1()` not `closeSection()`.

And, frankly, the slider code needs a rewrite.

In the `showSlides` function are you aware that

```js
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

will get all the slides, rather than just those of the chosen section, e.g. "painting"?

Which means that for any section apart from "figurative", the prev and next buttons don't at first appear to do anything as the user has to click through the hidden `style.width = "0%"` images from the closed sections before eventually being able to see the images from the selected section.